# Как создать репозиторий и скопировать туда свои готовые файлы?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Решил обезопасить себя и закинуть проект в git, конкретно на bitbucket. 
Git установлен, но пользовался до этого только *"pull-push"*.
Есть папка с проектом которую мне надо закинуть, в мануале написано:

```
mkdir /path/to/your/project
```

Мне там нужно прописать название папки или же полный путь до папки?
Или же мне нужно что-то другое?

Может использовать инструкцию "У меня уже есть проект"?
Если я буду закидывать свой проект, не закину ли я его случайно в аккаунт конторы в которой работаю?

Comment: Смотрите не закиньте случайно пароли и прочие секретики

Comment: Советую использовать меркуриал. Легче разруливаются мержи.

Comment: Заметил, что для форматирования вы используете html. Здесь доступен гораздо более простой Markdown: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. создайте в bitbucket новый репо (наверное, уже);
2. скопируйте его SSH URL – что-то вроде `git@bitbucket.org:drtvader/superproject.git` – убедитесь, что там ваше, а не конторы имя после двоеточия;
3. зайдите в папку вашего проекта у себя на компе;
4. `git init` инициализирует git проект;
5. `git add .` добавит в него все файлы и папки в текущей директории и глубже;
6. `git commit -m "initial commit"` – закоммитит их все;
7. `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:drtvader/superproject.git` – сюда подставляете скопированный во 2-м шаге URL вашего репо на Bitbucket;
8. `git push origin master` чтобы закинуть свежесозданный коммит на bitbucket.

Всё, вроде бы. Веток и тегов у вас пока нет. С BitBucket вы уже работали с этого компьютера для вашей организации, поэтому дальнейшие замечания, скорее всего, не пригодятся:

*A.* может понадобиться ответить `yes` при первом подключении к BitBucket с вашего компа в 8-м пункте с `git push..` - на вопрос о том, доверять ли такому-то сертификату от такого-то IP адреса.

*B.* если не пользовались раньше git'ом с этого компьютера, понадобится сконфигурить git – задать ваше имя латиницей и email – они будут указаны как автор коммитов с этого компа:

```
git config --global user.name Vassia Poupkin
git config --global user.email poupkin@mail.ru
```

*C.* может быть, не все файлы вы захотите контролировать git'ом – например, конфиги с паролями – заранее создайте файл `.gitignore` и занесите их названия туда, по одному на строке, чтобы git не обращал на них внимание.

*D.* создайте в корне проекта файл README.md в разметке [Markdown](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html) с описанием вашего проекта, его названием и почётными копирайтами – содержание этого файла BitBucket покажет на странице вашего проекта.

Comment: Дошли наконец руки заняться этим делом, но вот какая штука, в битбакет уже готовый ключ не закидывался (используется на другом аккаунте), создал другой. Сделал все по вашему гайду и при пуле он выдал мне ошибку, о том, что ключ неправильный. Может как-то ключ надо добавлять еще особым образом?

Comment: bibucket вас узнаёт по ключу. Соотв. ключ должен быть один. Если вам с одного компьютера приходится заходить в BB под разными аккаунтами – нужны доп. фокусы с ключами: указывать явно, какой из ключей использовать. Под Linux/OS X есть нехитрый [способ с отдельными ssh конфигами для аккаунтов](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/). Как это сделать в Windows – гуглите. У вас какая ОС?

Comment: win. хорошо, буду гуглить. Спасибо еще раз)